# How to handle application configuration and data?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, security, configuration

Microsofts preferred way to handle application configuration and runtime data seems obvious at a first glance: App.config, which will be stored in the application execution directory (C:\Program Files\ProductLocation in most cases.) where only privileged users have write access. (Makes sense to me, because a casual user shouldn't be able to alter essential application configurations).

For normal user configuration, there's a user.config which will be copied into each users personal application data directory (%APPDATA%).

But this leads to a few questions:

- How can I alter configurations for every user without executing the process as administrator?
- Where should I store application data that doesn't get deployed with the application, instead should be generated when the application is started the first time?
- How is it possible to have e.g. dynamic connections strings, like for a database health monitor application?

I checked out the program data folder (%PROGRAMDATA% -> C:\ProgramData), but it seems this place is read-only for the standard user. (Windows Installer does create folders in here if needed, but they're all read-only.) -> What happend to %ALLUSERS%?

---

**Example where the Microsoft way may fail in my eyes:**

A financial application where every user should store his information in the same database (a SqlCE file db), where as the application has to run with user privileges (I don't want to be administrator to manage my wallet). The application needs connection to a database that isn't available at runtime and may be generated in during the first run using EntityFramework. So it could be possible that even the connection string has to be dynamic, and not configured in the app.settings where such information is fixed.

- This is stupid! Users could read sensitive information from other users by directly accessing the file database!

  -> Security is not only a file permission thing, there could also be database users, certificates, cryptography etc.)

---

Do I have to develop my own settings handler as a workaround to the Microsoft intended way?

I guess this question is asked a numerous times on SO, but every answer I found showed up workarounds, different solutions. Questions regarding "best practice" are closed immediately, so I tried to provide a practical example here.